# For every $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\varepsilon$ > 0 , there exist $\,q,q'\in\mathbb Q$, such that $q<x<q'$ and $\left |q-q' \right |< \varepsilon$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm asked to prove that for every  $\varepsilon$ > 0 , there exists two rational numbers 
$q$ and $q'$ such that $q<x<q'$ and $\left |q-q'  \right |<\varepsilon$ where $x$ is a real number.

I have to confess that I've quite a hard time grasping the "concept of $\varepsilon$", some proofs where it is used are still a bit obscur to me.
Anyway, here is my try :

Let $w,x,y \in \mathbb R$ such that $w<x<y$ and we define $\varepsilon := y-w$.

I proved earlier in class that it always exists a rational number between two real numbers, i.e. we have $w<q<x<q'<y$ with $q,q' \in \mathbb Q$

Hence, for all $x \in \mathbb R$ we have $q<x<q'$ with  $\left |q-q'  \right |<\varepsilon$.

This proof seems a bit too "easy", and I guess there is something wrong with it. Can I actually define $\varepsilon$ as I wish ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not quite, although you have the right idea. You have to start with a given $\epsilon$ that you have no choice over, and chose $y, w$ accordingly. But that isn't too hard - given some $\epsilon$, just take $y = x+\frac{\epsilon }2$

Comment: The reason it is quite hard to grasp "concept of $\epsilon$" is probably the use of Greek letter. We could as well rephrase the question as "if $x,y$ are real and $y>0$ then show that there exist rationals $q,q'$ such that $q<x<q'$ and $q'-q< y$." This will be much easier to handle.

Comment: You can use the result that "between any two distinct real numbers there lies a rational number".

Answer (score 4):

Let $m$ be a positive integer such that
$$
\frac{2}{\varepsilon}<m.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor}{m} \leqslant x<\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor+1}{m}
$$ hence $$
\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor-1}{m} < x<\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor+1}{m}
$$
and
$$
0<\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor+1}{m}-\frac{\lfloor mx\rfloor-1}{m}=\frac{2}{m}<\varepsilon.
$$

Comment: @Did - Good observation. Corrected.

Comment: Typo in the second equation $\to \ldots <x<\ldots$